# Mobile site prefix and jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

How can you implement the common mobile site patterns easily with jsf2? Can i achieve it with prettyfaces?

Basically i want:

m.mysite/index renders mobileIndex.xhtml
mysite/index renders index.xhtml

I want the "m." prefix specifically and I can't figure out how.

Using primefaces, tomcat7 and prettyfaces. Cheers

Comment: For a complete solution see this posting http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19887

Comment: @Ravi put as answer so I can mark as answer, it looks perfect

Comment: @KarlKildén Just wondering whether prettyfaces is working on the mobile device as it is not for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete solution for you question is posted on the Primefaces forum and can be found here [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19887)

Here is the relevant code:

The ViewHandler code

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandler;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class MyViewHandlerWrapper extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    private ViewHandler wrapped;

    public KxRenderKit(ViewHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHandler getWrapped() {
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public String calculateRenderKitId(FacesContext context) {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String userAgent = req.getHeader("user-agent");
        String accept = req.getHeader("Accept");

        if (userAgent != null && accept != null) {
            UserAgentInfo agent = new UserAgentInfo(userAgent, accept);
            if (agent.isMobileDevice()) {
                return "PRIMEFACES_MOBILE";
            }
        }

        return this.wrapped.calculateRenderKitId(context);
    }
}
```

Implementation inside your Managed Bean

```
@PostConstruct
    public void myPostConstruct(){
        String renderKitId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getRenderKitId();        
        if(renderKitId.equalsIgnoreCase("PRIMEFACES_MOBILE")){
            //REDIRECT TO YOUR MOBILE PAGE
        }
    }
```

UserAgent detection code

UserAgent detection code

```
/* *******************************************
// Copyright 2010-2012, Anthony Hand
//
// File version date: April 23, 2012
//      Update:
//      - Updated DetectAmazonSilk(): Fixed an issue in the detection logic.  
//
// File version date: April 22, 2012 - Second update
//      Update: To address additional Kindle issues...
//      - Updated DetectRichCSS(): Excluded e-Ink Kindle devices. 
//      - Created DetectAmazonSilk(): Created to detect Kindle Fire devices in Silk mode. 
//      - Updated DetectMobileQuick(): Updated to include e-Ink Kindle devices and the Kindle Fire in Silk mode.  
//
// File version date: April 11, 2012
//      Update: 
//      - Added a new variable for the new BlackBerry Curve Touch (9380): deviceBBCurveTouch. 
//      - Updated DetectBlackBerryTouch() to support the new BlackBerry Curve Touch (9380).
//
// File version date: January 21, 2012
//      Update: 
//      - Moved Windows Phone 7 to the iPhone Tier. WP7.5's IE 9-based browser is good enough now.  
//      - Added a new variable for 2 versions of the new BlackBerry Bold Touch (9900 and 9930): deviceBBBoldTouch. 
//      - Updated DetectBlackBerryTouch() to support the 2 versions of the new BlackBerry Bold Touch (9900 and 9930). 
//      - Updated DetectKindle() to focus on eInk devices only. The Kindle Fire should be detected as a regular Android device.
//
// File version date: August 22, 2011
//      Update: 
//      - Updated DetectAndroidTablet() to fix a bug I introduced in the last fix!
//
// File version date: August 16, 2011
//      Update: 
//      - Updated DetectAndroidTablet() to exclude Opera Mini, which was falsely reporting as running on a tablet device when on a phone.
//
//
// LICENSE INFORMATION
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
// software distributed under the License is distributed on an
// "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND,
// either express or implied. See the License for the specific
// language governing permissions and limitations under the License. 
//
//
// ABOUT THIS PROJECT
//   Project Owner: Anthony Hand
//   Email: anthony.hand@gmail.com
//   Web Site: http://www.mobileesp.com
//   Source Files: http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/
//
//   Versions of this code are available for:
//      PHP, JavaScript, Java, ASP.NET (C#), and Ruby
//
// *******************************************
 */
package com.handinteractive.mobile;

/**
 * The DetectSmartPhone class encapsulates information about
 *   a browser's connection to your web site.
 *   You can use it to find out whether the browser asking for
 *   your site's content is probably running on a mobile device.
 *   The methods were written so you can be as granular as you want.
 *   For example, enquiring whether it's as specific as an iPod Touch or
 *   as general as a smartphone class device.
 *   The object's methods return true, or false.
 */
public class UAgentInfo {
    // User-Agent and Accept HTTP request headers

    private String userAgent = "";
    private String httpAccept = "";

    // Let's store values for quickly accessing the same info multiple times.
    public boolean isIphone = false;
    public boolean isAndroidPhone = false;
    public boolean isTierTablet = false;
    public boolean isTierIphone = false;
    public boolean isTierRichCss = false;
    public boolean isTierGenericMobile = false;

    // Initialize some initial smartphone string variables.
    public static final String engineWebKit = "webkit";

    public static final String deviceIphone = "iphone";
    public static final String deviceIpod = "ipod";
    public static final String deviceIpad = "ipad";
    public static final String deviceMacPpc = "macintosh"; //Used for disambiguation

    public static final String deviceAndroid = "android";
    public static final String deviceGoogleTV = "googletv";
    public static final String deviceXoom = "xoom"; //Motorola Xoom
    public static final String deviceHtcFlyer = "htc_flyer"; //HTC Flyer

    public static final String deviceSymbian = "symbian";
    public static final String deviceS60 = "series60";
    public static final String deviceS70 = "series70";
    public static final String deviceS80 = "series80";
    public static final String deviceS90 = "series90";

    public static final String deviceWinPhone7 = "windows phone os 7";
    public static final String deviceWinMob = "windows ce";
    public static final String deviceWindows = "windows";
    public static final String deviceIeMob = "iemobile";
    public static final String devicePpc = "ppc"; //Stands for PocketPC
    public static final String enginePie = "wm5 pie"; //An old Windows Mobile

    public static final String deviceBB = "blackberry";
    public static final String vndRIM = "vnd.rim"; //Detectable when BB devices emulate IE or Firefox
    public static final String deviceBBStorm = "blackberry95";  //Storm 1 and 2
    public static final String deviceBBBold = "blackberry97";  //Bold 97x0 (non-touch)
    public static final String deviceBBBoldTouch = "blackberry 99";  //Bold 99x0 (touchscreen)
    public static final String deviceBBTour = "blackberry96";  //Tour
    public static final String deviceBBCurve = "blackberry89";  //Curve 2
    public static final String deviceBBCurveTouch = "blackberry 938";  //Curve Touch 9380
    public static final String deviceBBTorch = "blackberry 98";  //Torch
    public static final String deviceBBPlaybook = "playbook"; //PlayBook tablet

    public static final String devicePalm = "palm";
    public static final String deviceWebOS = "webos"; //For Palm's line of WebOS devices
    public static final String deviceWebOShp = "hpwos"; //For HP's line of WebOS devices

    public static final String engineBlazer = "blazer"; //Old Palm
    public static final String engineXiino = "xiino"; //Another old Palm

    public static final String deviceKindle = "kindle";  //Amazon Kindle, eInk one
    public static final String engineSilk = "silk";  //Amazon's accelerated Silk browser for Kindle Fire

    public static final String deviceNuvifone = "nuvifone";  //Garmin Nuvifone

    //Initialize variables for mobile-specific content.
    public static final String vndwap = "vnd.wap";
    public static final String wml = "wml";

    //Initialize variables for other random devices and mobile browsers.
    public static final String deviceTablet = "tablet"; //Generic term for slate and tablet devices
    public static final String deviceBrew = "brew";
    public static final String deviceDanger = "danger";
    public static final String deviceHiptop = "hiptop";
    public static final String devicePlaystation = "playstation";
    public static final String deviceNintendoDs = "nitro";
    public static final String deviceNintendo = "nintendo";
    public static final String deviceWii = "wii";
    public static final String deviceXbox = "xbox";
    public static final String deviceArchos = "archos";

    public static final String engineOpera = "opera"; //Popular browser
    public static final String engineNetfront = "netfront"; //Common embedded OS browser
    public static final String engineUpBrowser = "up.browser"; //common on some phones
    public static final String engineOpenWeb = "openweb"; //Transcoding by OpenWave server
    public static final String deviceMidp = "midp"; //a mobile Java technology
    public static final String uplink = "up.link";
    public static final String engineTelecaQ = "teleca q"; //a modern feature phone browser
    public static final String devicePda = "pda"; //some devices report themselves as PDAs
    public static final String mini = "mini";  //Some mobile browsers put "mini" in their names.
    public static final String mobile = "mobile"; //Some mobile browsers put "mobile" in their user agent strings.
    public static final String mobi = "mobi"; //Some mobile browsers put "mobi" in their user agent strings.

    //Use Maemo, Tablet, and Linux to test for Nokia"s Internet Tablets.
    public static final String maemo = "maemo";
    public static final String linux = "linux";
    public static final String qtembedded = "qt embedded"; //for Sony Mylo
    public static final String mylocom2 = "com2"; //for Sony Mylo also

    //In some UserAgents, the only clue is the manufacturer.
    public static final String manuSonyEricsson = "sonyericsson";
    public static final String manuericsson = "ericsson";
    public static final String manuSamsung1 = "sec-sgh";
    public static final String manuSony = "sony";
    public static final String manuHtc = "htc"; //Popular Android and WinMo manufacturer

    //In some UserAgents, the only clue is the operator.
    public static final String svcDocomo = "docomo";
    public static final String svcKddi = "kddi";
    public static final String svcVodafone = "vodafone";

    //Disambiguation strings.
    public static final String disUpdate = "update"; //pda vs. update


    /**
     * Initialize the userAgent and httpAccept variables
     *
     * @param userAgent the User-Agent header
     * @param httpAccept the Accept header
     */
    public UAgentInfo(String userAgent, String httpAccept) {
        if (userAgent != null) {
            this.userAgent = userAgent.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (httpAccept != null) {
            this.httpAccept = httpAccept.toLowerCase();
        }

        //Intialize key stored values.
        initDeviceScan();
    }

    /**
     * Return the lower case HTTP_USER_AGENT
     * @return userAgent
     */
    public String getUserAgent() {
        return userAgent;
    }

    /**
     * Return the lower case HTTP_ACCEPT
     * @return httpAccept
     */
    public String getHttpAccept() {
        return httpAccept;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the device is an Iphone or iPod Touch
     * @return isIphone
     */
    public boolean getIsIphone() {
        return isIphone;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the device is in the Tablet Tier.
     * @return isTierTablet
     */
    public boolean getIsTierTablet() {
        return isTierTablet;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the device is in the Iphone Tier.
     * @return isTierIphone
     */
    public boolean getIsTierIphone() {
        return isTierIphone;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the device is in the 'Rich CSS' tier of mobile devices.
     * @return isTierRichCss
     */
    public boolean getIsTierRichCss() {
        return isTierRichCss;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the device is a generic, less-capable mobile device.
     * @return isTierGenericMobile
     */
    public boolean getIsTierGenericMobile() {
        return isTierGenericMobile;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Key Stored Values.
     */
    public void initDeviceScan() {
        this.isIphone = detectIphoneOrIpod();
        this.isAndroidPhone = detectAndroidPhone();
        this.isTierTablet = detectTierTablet();
        this.isTierIphone = detectTierIphone();
        this.isTierRichCss = detectTierRichCss();
        this.isTierGenericMobile = detectTierOtherPhones();
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an iPhone.
     * @return detection of an iPhone
     */
    public boolean detectIphone() {
        // The iPad and iPod touch say they're an iPhone! So let's disambiguate.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceIphone) != -1 && 
                !detectIpad() && 
                !detectIpod()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an iPod Touch.
     * @return detection of an iPod Touch
     */
    public boolean detectIpod() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceIpod) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an iPad tablet.
     * @return detection of an iPad
     */
    public boolean detectIpad() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceIpad) != -1
                && detectWebkit()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an iPhone or iPod Touch.
     * @return detection of an iPhone or iPod Touch
     */
    public boolean detectIphoneOrIpod() {
        //We repeat the searches here because some iPods may report themselves as an iPhone, which would be okay.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceIphone) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceIpod) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects *any* iOS device: iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad.
     * @return detection of an Apple iOS device
     */
    public boolean detectIos() {
        if (detectIphoneOrIpod() || detectIpad()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Detects *any* Android OS-based device: phone, tablet, and multi-media player.
     * Also detects Google TV.
     * @return detection of an Android device
     */
    public boolean detectAndroid() {
        if ((userAgent.indexOf(deviceAndroid) != -1) ||
          detectGoogleTV()) 
            return true;
        //Special check for the HTC Flyer 7" tablet. It should report here.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceHtcFlyer) != -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is a (small-ish) Android OS-based device
     * used for calling and/or multi-media (like a Samsung Galaxy Player).
     * Google says these devices will have 'Android' AND 'mobile' in user agent.
     * Ignores tablets (Honeycomb and later).
     * @return  detection of an Android phone
     */
    public boolean detectAndroidPhone() {
        if (detectAndroid() && (userAgent.indexOf(mobile) != -1)) 
            return true;
        //Special check for Android phones with Opera Mobile. They should report here.
        if (detectOperaAndroidPhone()) 
            return true;
        //Special check for the HTC Flyer 7" tablet. It should report here.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceHtcFlyer) != -1) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is a (self-reported) Android tablet.
     * Google says these devices will have 'Android' and NOT 'mobile' in their user agent.
     * @return detection of an Android tablet
     */
    public boolean detectAndroidTablet() {
        //First, let's make sure we're on an Android device.
        if (!detectAndroid())
            return false;

        //Special check for Opera Android Phones. They should NOT report here.
        if (detectOperaMobile()) 
            return false;
        //Special check for the HTC Flyer 7" tablet. It should NOT report here.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceHtcFlyer) != -1)
            return false;

        //Otherwise, if it's Android and does NOT have 'mobile' in it, Google says it's a tablet.
        if ((userAgent.indexOf(mobile) > -1)) 
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an Android OS-based device and
     * the browser is based on WebKit.
     * @return detection of an Android WebKit browser
     */
    public boolean detectAndroidWebKit() {
        if (detectAndroid() && detectWebkit()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is a GoogleTV.
     * @return detection of GoogleTV
     */
    public boolean detectGoogleTV() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceGoogleTV) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is based on WebKit.
     * @return detection of a WebKit browser
     */
    public boolean detectWebkit() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(engineWebKit) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is the Symbian S60 Open Source Browser.
     * @return detection of Symbian S60 Browser
     */
    public boolean detectS60OssBrowser() {
        //First, test for WebKit, then make sure it's either Symbian or S60.
        if (detectWebkit()
                && (userAgent.indexOf(deviceSymbian) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceS60) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

code continued in another answer

Answer (score 1):

UserAgent detection code continued:

```
    /**
     *
     * Detects if the current device is any Symbian OS-based device,
     *   including older S60, Series 70, Series 80, Series 90, and UIQ,
     *   or other browsers running on these devices.
     * @return detection of SymbianOS
     */
    public boolean detectSymbianOS() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceSymbian) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceS60) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceS70) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceS80) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceS90) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a 
     * Windows Phone 7 device.
     * @return detection of Windows Phone 7
     */
    public boolean detectWindowsPhone7() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceWinPhone7) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a Windows Mobile device.
     * Excludes Windows Phone 7 devices.
     * Focuses on Windows Mobile 6.xx and earlier.
     * @return detection of Windows Mobile
     */
    public boolean detectWindowsMobile() {
        //Exclude new Windows Phone 7.
        if (detectWindowsPhone7()) {
            return false;
        }
        //Most devices use 'Windows CE', but some report 'iemobile'
        //  and some older ones report as 'PIE' for Pocket IE.
        //  We also look for instances of HTC and Windows for many of their WinMo devices.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceWinMob) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceWinMob) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceIeMob) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(enginePie) != -1
                || (userAgent.indexOf(manuHtc) != -1 && userAgent.indexOf(deviceWindows) != -1) 
                || (detectWapWml() && userAgent.indexOf(deviceWindows) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }

        //Test for Windows Mobile PPC but not old Macintosh PowerPC.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(devicePpc) != -1 &&
                !(userAgent.indexOf(deviceMacPpc) != -1))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is any BlackBerry.
     * Includes the PlayBook.
     * @return detection of Blackberry
     */
    public boolean detectBlackBerry() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceBB) != -1 || 
            httpAccept.indexOf(vndRIM) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is on a BlackBerry tablet device.
     *    Example: PlayBook
     * @return detection of a Blackberry Tablet
     */
    public boolean detectBlackBerryTablet() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBPlaybook) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a BlackBerry device AND uses a
     *    WebKit-based browser. These are signatures for the new BlackBerry OS 6.
     *    Examples: Torch. Includes the Playbook.
     * @return detection of a Blackberry device with WebKit browser
     */
    public boolean detectBlackBerryWebKit() {
        if (detectBlackBerry() &&
            userAgent.indexOf(engineWebKit) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a BlackBerry Touch
     * device, such as the Storm, Torch, and Bold Touch. Excludes the Playbook.
     * @return detection of a Blackberry touchscreen device
     */
    public boolean detectBlackBerryTouch() {
        if (detectBlackBerry() &&
            (userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBStorm) != -1 ||
            userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBTorch) != -1 ||
            userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBBoldTouch) != -1 ||
                        userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBCurveTouch) != -1 )) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a BlackBerry device AND
     *   has a more capable recent browser. Excludes the Playbook.
     *   Examples, Storm, Bold, Tour, Curve2
     *   Excludes the new BlackBerry OS 6 and 7 browser!!
     * @return detection of a Blackberry device with a better browser
     */
    public boolean detectBlackBerryHigh() {
        //Disambiguate for BlackBerry OS 6 or 7 (WebKit) browser
        if (detectBlackBerryWebKit()) 
            return false;
        if (detectBlackBerry()) {
            if (detectBlackBerryTouch()
                    || userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBBold) != -1
                    || userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBTour) != -1
                    || userAgent.indexOf(deviceBBCurve) != -1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a BlackBerry device AND
     *   has an older, less capable browser.
     *   Examples: Pearl, 8800, Curve1
     * @return detection of a Blackberry device with a poorer browser
     */
    public boolean detectBlackBerryLow() {
        if (detectBlackBerry()) {
            //Assume that if it's not in the High tier, then it's Low
            if (detectBlackBerryHigh()
                    || detectBlackBerryWebKit()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is on a PalmOS device.
     * @return detection of a PalmOS device
     */
    public boolean detectPalmOS() {
        //Most devices nowadays report as 'Palm', but some older ones reported as Blazer or Xiino.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(devicePalm) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(engineBlazer) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(engineXiino) != -1) {
            //Make sure it's not WebOS first
            if (detectPalmWebOS()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is on a Palm device
     *    running the new WebOS.
     * @return detection of a Palm WebOS device
     */
    public boolean detectPalmWebOS() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceWebOS) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is on an HP tablet running WebOS.
     * @return detection of an HP WebOS tablet
     */
    public boolean detectWebOSTablet() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceWebOShp) != -1 && 
                userAgent.indexOf(deviceTablet) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a
     *    Garmin Nuvifone.
     * @return detection of a Garmin Nuvifone
     */
    public boolean detectGarminNuvifone() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceNuvifone) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check to see whether the device is any device
     *   in the 'smartphone' category.
     * @return detection of a general smartphone device
     */
    public boolean detectSmartphone() {
        return (isIphone 
                || isAndroidPhone
                || isTierIphone 
                || detectS60OssBrowser()
                || detectSymbianOS()
                || detectWindowsMobile()
                || detectWindowsPhone7()
                || detectBlackBerry()
                || detectPalmWebOS()
                || detectPalmOS()
                || detectGarminNuvifone());
    }

    /**
     * Detects whether the device is a Brew-powered device.
     * @return detection of a Brew device
     */
    public boolean detectBrewDevice() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceBrew) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects the Danger Hiptop device.
     * @return detection of a Danger Hiptop
     */
    public boolean detectDangerHiptop() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceDanger) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceHiptop) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects Opera Mobile or Opera Mini.
     * @return detection of an Opera browser for a mobile device
     */
    public boolean detectOperaMobile() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(engineOpera) != -1
                && (userAgent.indexOf(mini) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(mobi) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects Opera Mobile on an Android phone.
     * @return detection of an Opera browser on an Android phone
     */
    public boolean detectOperaAndroidPhone() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(engineOpera) != -1
                && (userAgent.indexOf(deviceAndroid) != -1
                && userAgent.indexOf(mobi) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects Opera Mobile on an Android tablet.
     * @return detection of an Opera browser on an Android tablet
     */
    public boolean detectOperaAndroidTablet() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(engineOpera) != -1
                && (userAgent.indexOf(deviceAndroid) != -1
                && userAgent.indexOf(deviceTablet) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects whether the device supports WAP or WML.
     * @return detection of a WAP- or WML-capable device
     */
    public boolean detectWapWml() {
        if (httpAccept.indexOf(vndwap) != -1
                || httpAccept.indexOf(wml) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an Amazon Kindle (eInk devices only).
     * Note: For the Kindle Fire, use the normal Android methods.
     * @return detection of a Kindle
     */
    public boolean detectKindle() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceKindle)!= -1 &&
            !detectAndroid()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current Amazon device is using the Silk Browser.
     * Note: Typically used by the the Kindle Fire.
     * @return detection of an Amazon Kindle Fire in Silk mode.
     */
    public boolean detectAmazonSilk() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(engineSilk)  != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Detects if the current device is a mobile device.
     *  This method catches most of the popular modern devices. 
     *  Excludes Apple iPads and other modern tablets.
     * @return detection of any mobile device using the quicker method
     */
    public boolean detectMobileQuick() {
        //Let's exclude tablets
        if (isTierTablet) {
            return false;
        }
        //Most mobile browsing is done on smartphones
        if (detectSmartphone()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (detectWapWml()
            || detectBrewDevice()
            || detectOperaMobile()) {
            return true;
        }

        if ((userAgent.indexOf(engineNetfront) != -1) 
            || (userAgent.indexOf(engineUpBrowser) != -1) 
            || (userAgent.indexOf(engineOpenWeb) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (detectDangerHiptop()
            || detectMidpCapable()
            || detectMaemoTablet()
            || detectArchos()) {
            return true;
        }

        if ((userAgent.indexOf(devicePda) != -1) &&
            (userAgent.indexOf(disUpdate) < 0)) //no index found
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (userAgent.indexOf(mobile) != -1) {
            return true;
        }

        //We also look for Kindle devices
        if (detectKindle()
                        || detectAmazonSilk()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is a Sony Playstation.
     * @return detection of Sony Playstation
     */
    public boolean detectSonyPlaystation() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(devicePlaystation) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is a Nintendo game device.
     * @return detection of Nintendo
     */
    public boolean detectNintendo() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceNintendo) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceWii) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(deviceNintendoDs) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is a Microsoft Xbox.
     * @return detection of Xbox
     */
    public boolean detectXbox() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceXbox) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an Internet-capable game console.
     * @return detection of any Game Console
     */
    public boolean detectGameConsole() {
        if (detectSonyPlaystation()
                || detectNintendo()
                || detectXbox()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device supports MIDP, a mobile Java technology.
     * @return detection of a MIDP mobile Java-capable device
     */
    public boolean detectMidpCapable() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceMidp) != -1
                || httpAccept.indexOf(deviceMidp) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is on one of the Maemo-based Nokia Internet Tablets.
     * @return detection of a Maemo OS tablet
     */
    public boolean detectMaemoTablet() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(maemo) != -1) {
            return true;
        } else if (userAgent.indexOf(linux) != -1
                && userAgent.indexOf(deviceTablet) != -1
                && !detectWebOSTablet()
                && !detectAndroid()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current device is an Archos media player/Internet tablet.
     * @return detection of an Archos media player
     */
    public boolean detectArchos() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceArchos) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Detects if the current browser is a Sony Mylo device.
     * @return detection of a Sony Mylo device
     */
    public boolean detectSonyMylo() {
        if (userAgent.indexOf(manuSony) != -1
                && (userAgent.indexOf(qtembedded) != -1
                || userAgent.indexOf(mylocom2) != -1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * The longer and more thorough way to detect for a mobile device.
     *   Will probably detect most feature phones,
     *   smartphone-class devices, Internet Tablets,
     *   Internet-enabled game consoles, etc.
     *   This ought to catch a lot of the more obscure and older devices, also --
     *   but no promises on thoroughness!
     * @return detection of any mobile device using the more thorough method
     */
    public boolean detectMobileLong() {
        if (detectMobileQuick()
                || detectGameConsole()
                || detectSonyMylo()) {
            return true;
        }

        //detect older phones from certain manufacturers and operators.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(uplink) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (userAgent.indexOf(manuSonyEricsson) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (userAgent.indexOf(manuericsson) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (userAgent.indexOf(manuSamsung1) != -1) {
            return true;
        }

        if (userAgent.indexOf(svcDocomo) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (userAgent.indexOf(svcKddi) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (userAgent.indexOf(svcVodafone) != -1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    //*****************************
    // For Mobile Web Site Design
    //*****************************

    /**
     * The quick way to detect for a tier of devices.
     *   This method detects for the new generation of
     *   HTML 5 capable, larger screen tablets.
     *   Includes iPad, Android (e.g., Xoom), BB Playbook, WebOS, etc.
     * @return detection of any device in the Tablet Tier
     */
    public boolean detectTierTablet() {
        if (detectIpad()
                || detectAndroidTablet()
                || detectBlackBerryTablet()
                || detectWebOSTablet()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * The quick way to detect for a tier of devices.
     *   This method detects for devices which can
     *   display iPhone-optimized web content.
     *   Includes iPhone, iPod Touch, Android, Windows Phone 7, Palm WebOS, etc.
     * @return detection of any device in the iPhone/Android/WP7/WebOS Tier
     */
    public boolean detectTierIphone() {
        if (isIphone
                || isAndroidPhone
                || (detectBlackBerryWebKit() 
                    && detectBlackBerryTouch())
        || detectWindowsPhone7()
                || detectPalmWebOS()
                || detectGarminNuvifone()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * The quick way to detect for a tier of devices.
     *   This method detects for devices which are likely to be capable
     *   of viewing CSS content optimized for the iPhone,
     *   but may not necessarily support JavaScript.
     *   Excludes all iPhone Tier devices.
     * @return detection of any device in the 'Rich CSS' Tier
     */
    public boolean detectTierRichCss() {
        boolean result = false;
        //The following devices are explicitly ok.
        //Note: 'High' BlackBerry devices ONLY
        if (detectMobileQuick()) {

                        //Exclude iPhone Tier and e-Ink Kindle devices.
            if (!detectTierIphone() && !detectKindle()) {

                //The following devices are explicitly ok.
                //Note: 'High' BlackBerry devices ONLY
                //Older Windows 'Mobile' isn't good enough for iPhone Tier.
                if (detectWebkit()
                    || detectS60OssBrowser()
                    || detectBlackBerryHigh()
                    || detectWindowsMobile()
                    || userAgent.indexOf(engineTelecaQ) !=
                    -1) {
                       result= true;
                } // if detectWebkit()
            } //if !detectTierIphone()
        } //if detectMobileQuick()
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * The quick way to detect for a tier of devices.
     *   This method detects for all other types of phones,
     *   but excludes the iPhone and RichCSS Tier devices.
     * @return detection of a mobile device in the less capable tier 
     */
    public boolean detectTierOtherPhones() {
        //Exclude devices in the other 2 categories
        if (detectMobileLong() 
            && !detectTierIphone() 
            && !detectTierRichCss()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Much appreciated work by Anthony Hand